# How to disconnect from a joinOnce NEHotspotConfiguration?

Tags: swift, nehotspotconfigurationmanager

I'm able to successfully connect to our IOT device's hotspot using `NEHotspotConfiguration`, however we need to be able to disconnect from the hotspot when they cancel the setup process.

Calling `NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.removeConfiguration()` only removes the config, but if the phone is currently connected to the hotspot this call has no effect and the device remains connected.

How can I disconnect from this hotspot? Seems like it should be simple!

Comment: It does disconnect from the hotspot it is connected to. Tried using `NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.removeConfiguration(forSSID: "testwifi")`

Comment: From a comment elsewhere I have found that if you set `joinOnce` to false then it does disconnect, but if true it stays connected: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116978

Comment: Having same issue, did you solve it somehow?

Comment: @bezoadam I wasn't able to do it using `joinOnce` in the end, I set this to false and had to add extra logic to account for it in my app's flow.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.getConfiguredSSIDs { configuration in
    
                print("configuration : \(configuration)")
    
                NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.removeConfiguration(forSSID: configuration[0])

NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.removeConfiguration(forHS20DomainName: configuration[0])
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior in iOS 15.2 when connecting to my IoT device: invoking removeConfiguration(forSSID:) does not disconnect an hotspot previously connected with joinOnce = true.

This is contrary to [Apple's own documentation on joinOnce](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration/2887518-joinonce), which says:

> To disconnect the device from a hotspot configured with joinOnce set
> to true, call removeConfiguration(forSSID:)

So, it seems to be a bug in either: a) iOS 15.2, or b) Apple's documentation.  I created a bug report here: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9954367, and I will reply when I hear back from them.

I also see this issue was discussed for earlier iOS versions (12.2, 12.3.1) in [this developer forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116978) without any resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the response and reporting the issue. I saw that thread but it's not the same specific issue, remove config does indeed work but not *while* the device is connected to that SSID. Seems like a glaring oversight on Apple's engineers that once the device is connected you can't programmatically disconnect from it. It's been a while since I looked at that code but maybe an option is to try and connect to a dummy SSID, I may try that next time I'm working on that project. (The link to the feedback you submitted shows it can't be found btw)

Comment: @Leon, the behavior you're seeing is consistent with the bug I reported.  More recently, the bug seems to have been fixed in iOS 15.4.  I would suggest that you try your test again with 15.4, but make sure you are connecting using applyConfiguration() with joinOnce = true.